# Lua 5.1 bitwise operations using arithmetic for 64bit numbers

Tags: c++, lua, cryptography, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Lua 5.1 does not yet support bitwise operators. The Lua environment I'm using is restricted and provides a bit32 library that allows bitwise operations with 32-bit numbers.

The issue is that I'm trying to backport an algorithm written in Lua 5.4 (poly1305), which you can find here: https://github.com/philanc/plc/blob/master/plc/poly1305.lua And this algorithm uses numbers larger than 32 bits, which makes the result incorrect in my environment.

You can find my backport of poly1305 https://pastebin.com/mfNhDqvw

I've done some research to perform bitwise operations using arithmetic, and I found functional wrappers, but they don't work with numbers larger than 32 bits. Would any of you be able to make them work with 64-bit numbers, or rewrite them completely if necessary?

```lua
local MOD = 2 ^ 32
local MODM = MOD - 1
 
local function memoize(f)
    local mt = { }
    local t = setmetatable( { }, mt)
    function mt:__index(k)
        local v = f(k)
        t[k] = v
        return v
    end
    return t
end
 
local function make_bitop_uncached(t, m)
    local function bitop(a, b)
        local res, p = 0, 1
        while a ~= 0 and b ~= 0 do
            local am, bm = a % m, b % m
            res = res + t[am][bm] * p
            a =(a - am) / m
            b =(b - bm) / m
            p = p * m
        end
        res = res +(a + b) * p
        return res
    end
    return bitop
end
 
local function make_bitop(t)
    local op1 = make_bitop_uncached(t, 2 ^ 1)
    local op2 = memoize( function(a) return memoize( function(b) return op1(a, b) end) end)
    return make_bitop_uncached(op2, 2 ^(t.n or 1))
end
 
local bxor1 = make_bitop( { [0] = { [0] = 0, [1] = 1 }, [1] = { [0] = 1, [1] = 0 }, n = 4 })
 
local function bxor(a, b, c, ...)
    local z = nil
    if b then
        a = a % MOD
        b = b % MOD
        z = bxor1(a, b)
        if c then z = bxor(z, c, ...) end
        return z
    elseif a then
        return a % MOD
    else
        return 0
    end
end
 
local function band(a, b, c, ...)
    local z
    if b then
        a = a % MOD
        b = b % MOD
        z =((a + b) - bxor1(a, b)) / 2
        if c then z = bit32_band(z, c, ...) end
        return z
    elseif a then
        return a % MOD
    else
        return MODM
    end
end
 
local function bnot(x) return(-1 - x) % MOD end
 
local function rshift1(a, disp)
    if disp < 0 then return lshift(a, - disp) end
    return math.floor(a % 2 ^ 32 / 2 ^ disp)
end
 
local function rshift(x, disp)
    if disp > 31 or disp < -31 then return 0 end
    return rshift1(x % MOD, disp)
end
 
local function lshift(a, disp)
    if disp < 0 then return rshift(a, - disp) end
    return(a * 2 ^ disp) % 2 ^ 32
end
 
local function rrotate(x, disp)
    x = x % MOD
    disp = disp % 32
    local low = band(x, 2 ^ disp - 1)
    return rshift(x, disp) + lshift(low, 32 - disp)
end
```

================================================================================
EDIT:
Following the feedback, I would like to add some additional information. Since you're not certain that the algorithm only deals with 32-bit numbers, I have decided to monitor the bitshift operations to demonstrate otherwise. Here are the modifications made to capture the values used in the bitshift operations of this algorithm:

```lua
lshift = function(a,b) print("a=["..a.."] b=["..b.."] - a << b = ["..(a << b).."]")  return a << b  end;
rshift = function(a,b) print("a=["..a.."] b=["..b.."] - a >> b = ["..(a >> b).."]") return a >> b  end;
```

Results on a standard 5.4 lua environnement with `text=1234123412341234` and `secret32B=12345678123456781234567812345678`:

```
[1] a=[926299444] b=[2] - a >> b = [231574861]
[2] a=[842086455] b=[4] - a >> b = [52630403]
[3] a=[892613426] b=[6] - a >> b = [13947084]
[4] a=[943142453] b=[8] - a >> b = [3684150]
[5] a=[858927412] b=[2] - a >> b = [214731853]
[6] a=[842085427] b=[4] - a >> b = [52630339]
[7] a=[825504562] b=[6] - a >> b = [12898508]
[8] a=[875770417] b=[8] - a >> b = [3420978]
[9] a=[10084375459231865] b=[26] - a >> b = [150268904]
[10] a=[6482263059657534] b=[26] - a >> b = [96593246]
[11] a=[2170453620770289] b=[26] - a >> b = [32342279]
[12] a=[2440835001604485] b=[26] - a >> b = [36371275]
[13] a=[3412223033429668] b=[26] - a >> b = [50846085]
[14] a=[271497234] b=[26] - a >> b = [4]
[15] a=[50524994] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[16] a=[17909233] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[17] a=[54122885] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[18] a=[30232228] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[19] a=[3061778] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[20] a=[3061783] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[21] a=[50524994] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[22] a=[17909233] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[23] a=[54122885] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[24] a=[4258090660] b=[31] - a >> b = [1]
[25] a=[50524994] b=[26] - a << b = [3390674950946816]
[26] a=[50524994] b=[6] - a >> b = [789453]
[27] a=[17909233] b=[20] - a << b = [18779191902208]
[28] a=[17909233] b=[12] - a >> b = [4372]
[29] a=[54122885] b=[14] - a << b = [886749347840]
[30] a=[54122885] b=[18] - a >> b = [206]
[31] a=[30232228] b=[8] - a << b = [7739450368]
[32] a=[1013049923] b=[32] - a >> b = [0]
[33] a=[2538816002] b=[32] - a >> b = [0]
[34] a=[2861859653] b=[32] - a >> b = [0]
[35] a=[1013049923] b=[8] - a >> b = [3957226]
[36] a=[3957226] b=[8] - a >> b = [15457]
[37] a=[15457] b=[8] - a >> b = [60]
[38] a=[60] b=[8] - a >> b = [0]
[39] a=[2538816002] b=[8] - a >> b = [9917250]
[40] a=[9917250] b=[8] - a >> b = [38739]
[41] a=[38739] b=[8] - a >> b = [151]
[42] a=[151] b=[8] - a >> b = [0]
[43] a=[2861859653] b=[8] - a >> b = [11179139]
[44] a=[11179139] b=[8] - a >> b = [43668]
[45] a=[43668] b=[8] - a >> b = [170]
[46] a=[170] b=[8] - a >> b = [0]
[47] a=[92658435] b=[8] - a >> b = [361947]
[48] a=[361947] b=[8] - a >> b = [1413]
[49] a=[1413] b=[8] - a >> b = [5]
[50] a=[5] b=[8] - a >> b = [0]
```

Inputs on my restricted env are the same, but the results mismatch on large numbers e.g `10084375459231865`. I guess it overflows ?

============================ EDIT2
Results on my restricted environnement:

```lua
[1] a=[926299444] b=[2] - a >> b = [231574861]
[2] a=[842086455] b=[4] - a >> b = [52630403]
[3] a=[892613426] b=[6] - a >> b = [13947084]
[4] a=[943142453] b=[8] - a >> b = [3684150]
[5] a=[858927412] b=[2] - a >> b = [214731853]
[6] a=[842085427] b=[4] - a >> b = [52630339]
[7] a=[825504562] b=[6] - a >> b = [12898508]
[8] a=[875770417] b=[8] - a >> b = [3420978]
[9] a=[1.0084375459232e+16] b=[26] - a >> b = [40]
[10] a=[6.4822629093887e+15] b=[26] - a >> b = [28]
[11] a=[2.1704535241771e+15] b=[26] - a >> b = [5]
[12] a=[2.4408349692622e+15] b=[26] - a >> b = [11]
[13] a=[3.4122229970584e+15] b=[26] - a >> b = [4]
[14] a=[17266828] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[15] a=[34473854] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[16] a=[55533743] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[17] a=[21780611] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[18] a=[60969828] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[19] a=[17266828] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[20] a=[17266833] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[21] a=[34473854] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[22] a=[55533743] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[23] a=[21780611] b=[26] - a >> b = [0]
[24] a=[4288828260] b=[31] - a >> b = [1]
[25] a=[34473854] b=[26] - a << b = [4160749568]
[26] a=[34473854] b=[6] - a >> b = [538653]
[27] a=[55533743] b=[20] - a << b = [183500800]
[28] a=[55533743] b=[12] - a >> b = [13558]
[29] a=[21780611] b=[14] - a << b = [371245056]
[30] a=[21780611] b=[18] - a >> b = [83]
[31] a=[60969828] b=[8] - a << b = [2723374080]
[32] a=[5053786813] b=[32] - a >> b = [758819517]
[33] a=[1886001423] b=[32] - a >> b = [1886001423]
[34] a=[3133030454] b=[32] - a >> b = [3133030454]
[35] a=[758819517] b=[8] - a >> b = [2964138]
[36] a=[2964138] b=[8] - a >> b = [11578]
[37] a=[11578] b=[8] - a >> b = [45]
[38] a=[45] b=[8] - a >> b = [0]
[39] a=[1886001423] b=[8] - a >> b = [7367193]
[40] a=[7367193] b=[8] - a >> b = [28778]
[41] a=[28778] b=[8] - a >> b = [112]
[42] a=[112] b=[8] - a >> b = [0]
[43] a=[3133030454] b=[8] - a >> b = [12238400]
[44] a=[12238400] b=[8] - a >> b = [47806]
[45] a=[47806] b=[8] - a >> b = [186]
[46] a=[186] b=[8] - a >> b = [0]
[47] a=[2504579774] b=[8] - a >> b = [9783514]
[48] a=[9783514] b=[8] - a >> b = [38216]
[49] a=[38216] b=[8] - a >> b = [149]
[50] a=[149] b=[8] - a >> b = [0]
```

As you can see, bitshift results are incorrect on large numbers

================= EDIT 3
As you can see on both outputs line 9

- On lua 5.4: `[9] a=[10084375459231865] b=[26] - a >> b = [150268904]`
- On lua 5.1: `[9] a=[1.0084375459232e+16] b=[26] - a >> b = [40]`

On Lua 5.1, a double conversion is done, losing precision.
On Lua 5.4, the number is kept as a long number keeping the precision.

So for Lua 5.1 we actually have `10084375459232000` which is incorrect, as it should be `10084375459231865` (last 3 digits wiped and replaced by 0, and rounded)

Any idea to prevent this ?

============ EDIT 4

Still, `print(10084375459232000 >> 26)` on Lua 5.4 does `150268904` and not `40`, so it's not even related to precision. But more likely an issue with doubles ? I'm a bit confused now

Comment: Lua 5.1 does not have 64-bit integers.  It has "double" numbers with 53-bit mantissa which can be used as if they were 53-bit integers.  Are 53-bit integers enough for poly1305?

Comment: I think it does yea, let me monitor what numbers are passed to bitwise functions and will report it here

Comment: Don't you need arithmetic modulo 2^128 for poly1305? You could represent numbers as several chunks of 32 bits

Comment: @ESkri well nvm, I don't even have to do this. If you take my backport and pasting it inside https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-lua-online/ the generated MAC is correct, so numbers don't exceed 53-bits for sure

Comment: The implementation you posted a link to requires only 32-bit numbers

Comment: @harold I'm really not into cryptography, I just backported this : https://github.com/philanc/plc/blob/master/plc/poly1305.lua and it's working on an unrestricted lua 5.4 env

Comment: @ESkri Well, when I did monitor the bitwise operations, especially on bit shifting, with e.g a << b = c, the result c would always differ in my restricted env

Comment: @ESkri when I did dump, a and b, a was sometimes superior of INT_MAX

Comment: @ESkri and as mentionned in my env specs: `bit.lshift(2147483648, 1) = 0, because 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 -> 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000)`

Comment: OK the linked implementation handles the 128-bit (and apparently 130-bit) numbers itself with multiple chunks

Comment: @harold what does that imply ?

Comment: @neth that you don't need to implement 128-bit or 130-bit arithmetic at least. Actually I also don't see where and why it would require 64-bit arithmetic. It seems carefully designed such that any time a number larger than 32 bits may be created, only the bottom 32 bits of it are needed and `& 0xffffffff` is used to deliberately throw away the excess (equivalently you can do a 32-bit operation that never computes the excess bits). But I did not do a 100% walkthrough of every operation there.

Comment: @harold hold on, let me show you bitshift operations done with `auth("1234123412341234","12345678123456781234567812345678")`

Comment: OK but to put it another way, just because some numbers larger than 32 bits temporarily existed, does not mean that the "extra" bits participate in the algorithm in a meaningful way. It looks to me like they are always thrown away soon after their creation, though I may have missed some case here or there.

Comment: I see the individual results of the shifts, but my point is those shifts are used in a context such as `((h1 >>  6) | (h2 << 20)) & 0xffffffff` for example, and yes here `h2 << 20` could be a number that doesn't fit in 32 bits, but that doesn't matter for the overall computation.

Comment: Then I don't really get why the polyMAC generated on my restricted env is incorrect. The only differences that I could find are the bitwise operation results. For me it's obviously the issue but I might be wrong

Comment: Try to normalize every result of addition.  For example, after `h0 = h0 + ...` insert `h0 = h0 % 2^32`

Comment: @Eskri Edited again the thread with results on my restricted env, if it gives you a better idea of the problem. Let me try your proposal ESKri but I'm really uncomfortable with this algorithm

Comment: By looking at [the C code](https://github.com/floodyberry/poly1305-donna/blob/master/poly1305-donna-32.h), one thing that stands out to me now is that eg `h0*r0` (and related expressions) compute a 26+26 = 52-bit result, summing 5 of them can be too much for a Lua number, depending on the exact values involved. For the right shift that takes `d0` (etc) it's fine if it makes a 32-bit result, but it needs to take a large number as input so it must not do `x % MOD` on its input.

Comment: @ESKri I tried your proposal without good results, probably because I have no clue about what I'm actually doing :/

Comment: I did some researches and lua 5.3+ came with a new type: Integers. As you can see on both output results, first results (on lua 5.4) have integers. On the second, we clearly see the double conversion, and doubles lose precision right?

Comment: @harold am I right ?

Comment: @harold I have added one more edit

Comment: @ESkri i've added one more important edit

Comment: 10084375459231865 would indeed be rounded when converted to a double, but I think the printed result is misleading (simply dropping some decimals, which is not how doubles work) since it would be rounded to 10084375459231864

Comment: @harold indeed, I made an EDIT 4 regarding that statement

Comment: I don't know what to do tbh, my knowledge in both bit manipulation and cryptography is ridiculous

Comment: To clarify, bitshifting gives a wrong result as soon as the number is converted to double

Comment: So I can only assume that the bit representation of a double is leading to this incorrect result

Comment: @harold so, I have no way to fix it ?

Comment: It's possible, but it looks fairly annoying to me, particularly managing the large products and adding them. Maybe it's easier to port the [version of the C code that doesn't use 64-bit types for those products](https://github.com/floodyberry/poly1305-donna/blob/master/poly1305-donna-16.h)

Comment: @harold porting your C++ link to lua worked, ty ;) But this thread is sadly not solved, maybe u wanna make an answer